# EWS Managed API - How to find out if the user is the owner of calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar, exchangewebservices

I am trying to figure out what permissions user have to certain calendar folder. I am checking [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.permissions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_Folder_Permissions) property, but it usually contains only 2 permissions - for default and anonymous standard users (no permissions for the owner of the calendar).

How can I check if the user is the owner and can edit events inside this calendar? Some of the calendars User have access are the shared ones so not all of them can be edited but Permissions are the same for all of them (only default and anonymous users permissions). I guess there must be some other property to check if the user can edit events inside the calendar or not.

Comment: The StoreId will tell you if the calendar is located in the users Mailbox or not (eg if its the same as the Inbox folder etc). If a Calendar is in the users mailbox they generally have owner rights on it. The other one would be check the effective rights https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.effectiverights?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api

Comment: effective rights in my case always return all the rights available - even if this is read-only calendar like 'US holidays' or shared one... How to get StoreId?

Comment: You can use ConvertId or use the Extended property https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/629a9f5b-4796-4754-9739-def934f82976/ews-retrieving-prstoreentryid-value?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment . Those holiday calendar folder generally only have a client block (vai an extended folder field) so while you can't modify them using Outlook or OWA you should still be able to modify them via EWS